# Target file in Ant NetBeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

My `NetBeans` project creates `my.jar` file in `/dist/` directory. Trying to edit `build.xml` to copy this file to another location using ssh. But how to know what is target file name property?

```
<property name="username"  value="aaa"/>
        <property name="password"  value="bbb"/>
        <property name="ip"  value="10.1.100.55"/>
        <property name="dir"  value="/opt/aaa/"/>

        <scp file="${dist.jar.dir}${??target??}" todir="${username}:${password}@${ip}:${dir}" trust="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Netbeans project has a `nbproject/project.properties` file, which gets included in `build.xml` (indirectly) and contains lots of useful variables - including the one that contains a file path to the built jar file. It should be called `dist.jar`.

```
 <scp file="${dist.jar}" todir="${username}:${password}@${ip}:${dir}" trust="true" />
```

Check the actual properties file for more variable names, such as `dist.dir`, `src.dir`, etc.